# How to exclude Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.* DLLs from publishing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've written .NET Standard 2.1 library component that relies on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc v2.2.0 package, which indirectly references Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll, MicrosoftCode.Analysis.dll, and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.dll. When I reference my component from .NET Core 3.1 app site and publish the site, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.* dlls are also published. Is there a way to exclude Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.* dlls from being published? I don't need them for production.

Here are my references from .NET Standard 2.1 CSPROJ file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="3.3.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your package references from your Net Standard's csproj file?

Comment: See my original post. I added references from csproj file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the issue comes from referencing the `AspNetCore` packages directly.

If you can change your class library to target `netcoreapp3.1` instead of `netstandard`, you can replace those by using a `FrameworkReference` instead. Note that `FrameworkReference` is only valid for assemblies targetting Net Core 3.x and up. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Alternatively, if you need to support both `netstandard` and `netcoreapp`, you can use conditional references.

```xml
<!-- Framework reference for netcoreapp -->
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.1' ">
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Common dependencies -->
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="3.3.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- netstandard dependencies -->
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation" Version="3.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="3.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="3.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" Version="3.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions" Version="3.1.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="3.1.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="3.1.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that I had to guess which package references your package library need, so you'll need to adapt as needed

Comment: Thanks! That was it. The frameworkreference part was the key to this, since that's the way to include ASP .NET Core APIs from library component. After I googled it, I came across this Microsoft article that explained it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio